# Progressive JPG downloading with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, swift, jpeg, nsurlconnection, nsdata

I'm currently trying to create a progressive JPG loader. When a large image is passed into my NSURLConnection it seems to cut half of the image away.

Here is my `didReceiveData` method and the image the data is assigned to:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    if let img: UIImage = UIImage(data: data){
        imageView.image = img
    }
    print("didReceiveData")
}
```

It seems to skip the last chunk of data to complete the image. An example image is:

[image: Greyed image]

This image is passed to the `connectionDidFinishLoading` as completed but clearly isn't. Anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen?

Answer (score 0):

The delegate `optional public func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData)` suppose to be callback to load data incrementally. Every time it gets called, you will receive the newly available data. So that if you try to set create image with the received data, it will not be the completed image. Instead, you should try this

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var receivedData = NSMutableData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let imageURL = "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_feature/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=75o-jlD5";
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: imageURL)!)
        let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
        urlConnection?.start()
    }

extension ViewController: NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        self.receivedData.appendData(data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
        self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: receivedData)
    }
}
```

I hope this would help you.